# How to find indexes of 5 the biggest elements in vector?

Tags: c++, stl

How to find indexes of 5 the biggest elements in vector ?
For example `std::vector<int>` how to find indexes of 5 biggest values but not to change original vector ?

Comment: Iterate over it and compare the current values with the 5 largest ones before it? That, or copy, sort, take the top 5.

Comment: @slugonamission: A bit better than sorting would be using `nth_element`... although that will be worse than going over the container linearly and maintaining the list of the 5 largest elements seen

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - aha, I never knew about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

`std::partial_sort( v.begin(), v.begin()+5, v.end() )` sorts a vector in a way, that the 5 smallest values are sorted and at the beginning of `v`. The rest is left unsorted.

Since you want the indices and keep the original:
Fill a new vector with numbers from 0..n-1 and supply a comparison function that does `v[a] > v[b]` instead of `a > b`:

```
struct Comp{
    Comp( const vector<int>& v ) : _v(v) {}
    bool operator ()(int a, int b) { return _v[a] > _v[b]; }
    const vector<int>& _v;
}

vector<int> vx;
vx.resize(v.size());
for( int i= 0; i<v.size(); ++i ) vx[i]= i;
partial_sort( vx.begin(), vx.begin()+5, vx.end(), Comp(v) );
```

`vx[0..4]` contains the indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy from the original vector, and partially sort it with a dedicated algorithm from the STL `nth_element` :

```
bool cmp (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }    
int main () {
      vector<int> myvector;
      vector<int>::iterator it;

      // set some values:
      for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);   // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

      random_shuffle (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());

      // using default comparison (operator <):
      std::vector<int> copy_of_orig = myvector;
      nth_element (copy_of_orig.begin(), copy_of_orig.begin()+5, copy_of_orig.end(), cmp);
      // Display the first five biggest elts.
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << copy_of_orig[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for the indices, so you wouldn't copy the vector, but fill it with the values `0,...myvector.size()-1` (or pointers/iterators to vectorelements) and you'd need an indirect comparison

Answer (score 1):

1 solution:

The solution is O(n), where n is the number of elements in the vector being examined.

create a dequeue of vector iterators of length 5, initialized with NULL
read the elements of the vector under examination and push_back the index {the idea is to push the new index in the front or back depending upon whether the new element data read is smaller than rear index's data or greater than the front index's data, if the data already in the dequeue is NULL, then whether you push_front or push_back, it doesn't matter}. This would maintain the dequeue in the sorted from from front to back.

If the new data being read is greater than the front data, then remove the rear and push the current data's iterator in front; else do nothing

At the end of the iteration the dequeue will have top five element's iterators.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant way, but I'm to tired to find it right now. You could do something like this (untested, so no guarantees it works out of the box, particulary in corner cases, but it should):

```
std::array<int, 5> indices = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};//-1 used as invalid index for cases where myVec.size()<5
for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        if((indices[j] == - 1) || (myVec[i] > myVec[indices[j]]))
        {
            std::copy_backward(indices.begin() + j, indices.end() - 1, indices.end());
            indices[j] = i;
            break;
        }
}
```

It maintains a list of the 5 biggest elements. For each element of the vector it will start with the biggest element, test if the new one is bigger, if yes shift the indices down and insert as the first, otherwise test for the second biggest and so on. Doesn't modify the `vector` and runs in `O(n)` with pretty low overhead.

In case you can't use C++11, you can always use an `std::vector` (or `int[5]` if you really want to) instead of `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this:

```
  int largestNumbers [5]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  for each( const int i in data ){
  {
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++){
       if (i > largestNumber[index]){
          largestNumber[index] = i;
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like C++ to me.

Comment: Two problems with this code: 1) The OP asked for indices, not values. 2) for a sequence `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` this would end with `largestNumbers` being `{5,5,5,5,5}`.