# Sampling without replacement with unequal probabilites -- linear run time possible?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, random

In search for a [faster weighted sampling without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113650/faster-weighted-sampling-without-replacement), the following question came up:

Is there an algorithm that implements random sampling without replacement with unequal selection probabilities using *linear* time in the size of the input? An O(n log n) implementation has been suggested in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140787/select-random-k-elements-from-a-list-whose-elements-have-weights) -- can this be improved?

Comment: I imagine one should be able to modify a [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) for this purpose, but it probably won't be easy.

Comment: Google `Pareto sampling` and `Conditional Poisson Sampling`. You'll eventually reach this: http://books.google.com/books/about/Sampling_Algorithms.html?id=2auW1rVAwGMC

Comment: Alright, I'm clearly missing something. Constructing a roulette wheel for selection is a linear operation. Searching is an O(log n) operation. Searching and then reconstructing the wheel ought to take O(n + log n) = O(n) time. What am I missing?

Comment: @RyanMarcus: It's about sampling `n` items, essentially a permutation.

Comment: Consider asking cs-related questions in [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).