# sample() command is too slow in R

Tags: r, random

I want to create a random subset of a `data.table` `df` that is very large (around 2 million lines). 
The data table has a weight column, `wgt` that indicates how many observation each line represents. 
To generate the vector of row numbers I want to extract, I proceed as follows:

I get the exact number of observations :

```
ns<- length(df$wgt)
```

I get the number of desired lines (30% of the sample):

```
lines<-round(0.3*ns)
```

I compute the vector of probabilities:

```
pr<-df$wgt/sum(df$wgt)
```

And then I compute the vector of line numbers to get the subsample:

```
ssout<-sample(1:ns, size=lines, probs=pr)
```

The final aim is to subset the data using `df[ssout,]`. However, R gets stuck when computing `ssout`.

Is there a faster/more efficient way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `sample.int` will trim a little bit off if you specify all the arguments, which will also force you to *not* create the `1:ns` vector in the first place (as @DavidArenburg suggested by skipping the `1:` part)

Comment: Judging by your description ("wgt that indicates how many observation each line represents"), you should be sampling with replacement. If one line has a weight of ten percent, you should be able to draw it multiple times.

Comment: I guess this doesn't really have anything to do with data.table (which it's tagged with); I'm not sure though...

Comment: If you decide that you **do** want to sample without replacement, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113650/faster-weighted-sampling-without-replacement (an amazing set of answers there!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that `df` is a summary description of a data set that has repeated observations (with `wgt` being the count of repetitions). In that case, the only useful way to sample from it would be with replacement; and a proper 30% sample would be 30% of the real population, `.3*sum(wgt)`:

```
# example data
wgt <- sample(10,2e6,replace=TRUE)
nobs<- sum(wgt)
pr  <- wgt/sum(wgt)

# select rows
system.time(x <- sample.int(2e6,size=.3*nobs,prob=pr,replace=TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.20    0.02    0.22
```

Sampling rows without replacement takes forever on my computer, but is also something that I don't think one needs to do here.

Comment: +1; an example that shows why sampling without replacement is wrong is a scenario where all the weights are 0 except for one (or all are equal to 1, and one is ridiculously large).